# What differences exist between an app pool / web application created manually, compared to one created with a DevOps agent via a release pipeline?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an ASP.NET Core application being deployed to multiple locations, exhibiting different behavior depending on whether the IIS app pool and site were created manually (using the IIS point-and-click UI) or whether they were created via an Azure Agent from a release pipeline (composed of two tasks: an "IIS web app manage" task to create app pool and web app, and an "IIS web app deploy" task to copy the contents).

The two sites have identical files and file permissions. The two app pools have identical configuration files.

The site created manually is operating correctly. When an error occurs, it's being captured by ASP.NET Core middleware defined by an app.UseStatusCodePages() directive. Exceptions on the site being created by the Azure Agent are not handled by the application and instead IIS is returning the error page defined at the site level. The "Error Pages" configurations for all sites are identical (not edited).

I have been unable to find any difference in configuration to account for the different app behavior, but I have reproduced this difference on two different IIS servers.

Can anyone suggest another place to look for application configuration differences?

Comment: In addition to the configuration file, there are also some settings that will affect when you publish the application. You can use the error message to find the problem.

Comment: @samwu there are no error messages; there are no differences other than site names in the deployment logs.

Comment: What configuration information did you compare? Have you compared the configuration files under `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config`?

Comment: In the path you indicated, I compared versions of the applicationHost.config file after creating sites in various ways. An app pool is also being created for each site. Those configuration files seem to be copies of the applicationHost.config and I found them in C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\{appPool}\{appPool}.config